# Why does batch file execution end unexpected on entering nothing on a user prompt?

Tags: batch-file

I try to make a batch file which asks the user a question (just as a test for if and else statements) and waits for the answer input by the user.

I tried to use:

```
@echo off
echo hi!
pause
CLS
echo how are you?
set /p what=
if %what%==Good (
GOTO good
) else (
GOTO what )

:Good
CLS
echo cool!
pause
GOTO end

:what
CLS
echo what?
pause
GOTO end

:end
```

The goal was to go to label `what` and continue there the batch file processing on user inputs anything other than `Good`.

But if nothing is entered by the user because of pressing only <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, the execution of the batch script just ends rather than going to code below label `what`. Also if some other things with spaces are typed on prompt, the batch file just ends the script as well.

Why does batch file execution end unexpected on entering nothing on a user prompt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set /P` prompts the user for a string. The user has the freedom

1. to enter what you are asking for,
2. just hit <kbd>RETURN</kbd> or <kbd>ENTER</kbd> without entering anything at all,
3. enter bad strings like

   ```
   a == a rd /s /q "%TEMP%" & rem
   ```

The last example results with your batch code in deletion of the user's folder for temporary files. So please don't try that user input with your batch file.

When the user enters nothing at all on prompt, the specified environment variable keeps its current value. In your case with environment variable `what` not defined at all on first run, it is still not defined after the user prompt and therefore the next command line executed by `cmd.exe` after preprocessing the command line is:

```
if ==Good (
```

So the left operand is missing and Windows command interpreter exits the execution of the batch file because of this syntax error as it can be seen on running this batch file from within a command prompt window instead of double clicking on the batch file. See also [Debugging a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42448601/3074564).

To make such a command prompt safe against no input or even bad input, use the following code:

```
@echo off
cls
echo Hi!
echo/
set "UserInput="
set /P "UserInput=How are you? "
if not defined UserInput goto WrongInput
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
if /I "!UserInput!" == "Good" endlocal & set "UserInput=" & goto Good
endlocal
set "UserInput="

:WrongInput
echo/
echo What?
echo/
pause
goto :EOF

:Good
echo/
echo Cool!
echo/
pause
```

First the environment variable `UserInput` is definitely deleted before prompting the user.

After the user prompt an **IF** condition is used to check if the variable `UserInput` is still not defined which means the user has not input anything at all if that condition is true.

But if the user has entered a string, a new [local environment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38676582/3074564) is setup with enabled delayed environment variable expansion, and the value of `UserInput` is compared case-insensitive with the string `"Good"` using delayed environment variable expansion. This prevents on accidentally or intentionally wrong input that the batch file execution exits due to a syntax error caused by the user input or do something completely different than being designed for.

In this case the local environment with enabled delayed environment variable expansion is no longer needed after string comparison which always includes also the double quotes around the strings on both sides. Therefore the previous environment is immediately restored in any case.

Well, it is valid to omit `if not defined UserInput` because of using surrounding double quotes on the two compared strings because the left string can't be empty anymore. And in general it is advisable to define a local environment for a batch file in case of being ever called later from other batch files or from within a command prompt window.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
cls
echo Hi!
echo/
set "UserInput="
set /P "UserInput=How are you? "
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
if /I "!UserInput!" == "Good" endlocal & goto Good
endlocal

echo/
echo What?
echo/
pause
goto EndBatch

:Good
echo/
echo Cool!
echo/
pause

:EndBatch
endlocal
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `cls /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

See also following questions with their answers for even more details and important facts to know on using environment variables within a batch file:

- [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564)
- [Symbol equivalent to NEQ, LSS, GTR, etc. in Windows batch files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47386323/3074564)
- [set /p with spaces in variable value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40821580/3074564)
- [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564)
- [Where does GOTO :EOF return to?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37518000/3074564)
- DosTips forum topic [ECHO. FAILS to give text or blank line - Instead use ECHO/](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=774)